# Android:Navigation between Fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, onbackpressed

I am developing an android app.Navigation Drawer contains three items fragment1, fragment2, fragment3.Now i am in fragment1 and i open fragment2 then from fragment2 i open fragment1 then again from fragment1 i open fragment2.I do this multiple times(3-4 times) and when i back press those fragments keeps on appearing in the reverse order.But i want something like this: Even if i switch fragments multiple times the back transition should happen only once like from fragment2 to fragment1 only and not again to  fragment1.

Answer (score 0):

Implement back stack with some primary id for fragment to check whether that fragment is in stack or not if its their than delete that position and insert new one in top.

Here is a link for same. but what i mentioned about that you have implement. Its back Stack simple working example
https://github.com/rathodchintan/Fragment-Back-Stack